# How can I define a ForEach loop on the basis of the existing ForAll loop?

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

Is there a way to define new command in `algpseudocode` based on existing one? In particular, in my document I need to use both `\ForAll` and `\ForEach` commands. It turns out that just renaming `\ForAll` doesn't work for me. I would like to define a new command `\ForEach` in such a way that it keeps all the functionalities of `\ForAll` (including typesetting "do" and "end for", and indenting all states inside the loop).

The code below shows what I've tried so far, but obviously that's not the way to go. I need lines 3,4,5 to be shifted together with the new command, and "end for" to be typeset.

```
\documentclass{article}      % Specifies the document class

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\algnewcommand\algorithmicforeach{\textbf{for each:}}
\algnewcommand\ForEach{\item[ \algorithmicforeach]}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm} \caption{Iterative Policy Evaluation Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require $\pi$, the policy to be evaluated
\State Initilize $V(s) = 0$, for all $s \in \mathcal S^+$
\Repeat
\ForEach {$s \in \mathcal S $}
\State $v \gets V(s)$
\State $V(s) \gets \sum_a \pi(s,a) \sum_{s'} \mathcal P_{ss'}^a [ \mathcal R_{ss'}^a + \gamma V(s')$
\State $\Delta \gets \max(\Delta, |v- V(s)|)$
%\EndFor
\Until {$\Delta < \theta \text{ (a small positive number)}$}
\Ensure $V \approx V^\pi$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the `algpseudocode` package, the `ForAll` loop is defined as follows:

```
\algnewcommand\algorithmicforall{\textbf{for all}}
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForAll}[1]{\algorithmicforeall\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}
```

You can simply define a `ForEach` loop that mimicks a `ForAll` one as follows:

```
\algnewcommand\algorithmicforeach{\textbf{for each}}
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForEach}[1]{\algorithmicforeach\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}      % Specifies the document class

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}


\algnewcommand\algorithmicforeach{\textbf{for each}}
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForEach}[1]{\algorithmicforeach\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm} \caption{Iterative Policy Evaluation Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require $\pi$, the policy to be evaluated
\State Initilize $V(s) = 0$, for all $s \in \mathcal S^+$
\Repeat
\ForEach {$s \in \mathcal S $}
\State $v \gets V(s)$
\State $V(s) \gets \sum_a \pi(s,a) \sum_{s'} \mathcal P_{ss'}^a [ \mathcal R_{ss'}^a + \gamma V(s')$
\State $\Delta \gets \max(\Delta, |v- V(s)|)$
\EndFor
\Until {$\Delta < \theta \text{ (a small positive number)}$}
\Ensure $V \approx V^\pi$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be just `end`instead of `EndFor`