# Hide Algorithm environment

Tags: environments, algorithms

I would like to hide the Algorithm environment as shown in the attached pic below.
That is please remove "Algorithm 8.1" which is highlighted in blude.

[image]

The code is provided below:

```
 \begin{algorithm}\label{al:8.1}\end{algorithm}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{| l ||l| }
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{ Algorithm \ref{al:8.1}: Obtaining weights (Off-line)}} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{INPUT } &  $\omega_{k}^{j}, (k<m)$, $\phi(l,k)$, $H_l^j$, $R_l^j$ \\
        \hline
        \textbf{OUTPUT} & $\omega_{k}^{j} (k\geq m)$ \\
        \hline
        1 & \textbf{INITIALIZE } $\omega_{k}^{j}, (k<m)$ \\
        \hline
        2 & \textbf{FOR} each $k\geq m$ \textbf{DO} OP \ref{op:8.1} \\
        \hline
        3 & \textbf{STORE} $\omega_{k}^{j}$ \\
        \hline
        4 & $k$ $\gets$ $k+1$ \\
        \hline
        5 & \textbf{GOTO} 2\\
        \hline
        6 & \textbf{END}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular} 
\end{center}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `tabular` environment to specify an algorithm in `LaTex`. Use some packages like [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) and [algpseudocode](/questions/tagged/algpseudocode). Here is an example of the algorithm in your picture, where the definition of the *for each* loop comes from here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149166.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\algnewcommand{\Initialize}[1]{%
  \State \textbf{Initialize} #1
}

\algnewcommand{\Store}[1]{%
  \State \textbf{Store} #1
}

\algnewcommand{\Goto}[1]{%
  \State \textbf{Goto} #1
}

% for each loop
% based on: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149166
\algnewcommand\algorithmicforeach{\textbf{for each}}
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForEach}[1]{\algorithmicforeach\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}

% algorithm number based on section
\counterwithin{algorithm}{section}

\begin{document}
% set section number to 8
\setcounter{section}{8}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Obtaining weights (Off-line)}
    \label{alg:8.1}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Require{$\omega_{k}^{j}, (k<m)$, $\phi(l,k)$, $H_l^j$, $R_l^j$}
        \Ensure{$\omega_{k}^{j} (k\geq m)$}
        \Initialize{$\omega_{k}^{j}, (k<m)$}
        \ForEach{$k \geq m$}\label{alg:8.1_line2}
            \State{OP~\ref{op:8.1}}
        \EndFor
        \Store{$\omega_{k}^{j}$}
        \State{$k$ $\gets$ $k+1$}
        \Goto{Line~\ref{alg:8.1_line2}}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

% to have a reference for op:8.1
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{\dots}
    \label{op:8.1}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output result]